# The political positions of RT pundits

Tags: russian-federation, media, political-spectrum

I am curious to know how one would characterize the political positions of Russia Today (RT) pundits using a political spectrum. I know the political positions of any one RT pundit may (probably will) differ from those of another; but on the whole, RT pundits hold fairly similar views. Among these include (and note these are rather simplified):

- The West (USA, UK, NATO, EU, Israel, and other Anglophone nations) is 'bad', 'imperialist', 'woke', and 'authoritarian' (and so is Western media), while Russia and China are 'victims of Western hegemony', 'strong', 'powerful' and 'good for the world'. RT pundits seem to be horrified by Western 'imperialism' and 'authoritarianism' (e.g. the imprisonment of Assange), but ignore the authoritarian detention of political prisoners by 'anti-Western' nations such as China and Russia.
- They seem to support politicians such as Tulsi Gabbard, Donald Trump, Jeremy Corbyn, and Bernie Sanders, while being opposed to politicians such as Hillary Clinton, Barrack Obama, and Tony Blair.
- On social issues, they seem to be more socially conservative, being mostly opposed to 'wokeism' and political correctness.
- etc.

My question is: Where on the political spectrum do (at least most) RT pundits stand?

Comment: Note: This question is not an expression of my political views; I am merely curious to know where RT pundits stand politically.

Comment: I think (might be wrong here) that this question might be better received if it leaves out the part about RT pundits and instead asks, “for somebody with these political views, what would their political position be?”

Comment: Not my DV or CV, but does this matter much? It's clear that the main drive why someone is invited to write for RT in re the West is to (at least) saw doubt in the "Western system" and comment on bad news regarding it. Not a new strategy actually, as it has root in the Soviet practices. "and you're lynching negroes"

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by "the" political spectrum -- that is, "the" implies there is only one universal model of political spectrum, but political science offers [a whole bunch of spectrum models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_spectrum), and some of these models are mutually incompatible.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but would prefer 2 changes to the question. Pundit replaced with just "RT", and bullet 1 with 'Bad'/'Woke' completely removed.

Comment: I'm with @agc, political spectrum is vague and the answer will largely depend on whose standards, individually and regionally you are applying. Otherwise, the OP basically answered their own question with the bullet points.